# How can I upgrade the firmware of an RCX 1.0 to an RCX 2.0?

Tags: rcx

I have an RCX 1.0 set from 1998 and I would like to upgrade the RCX 1.0 to RCX 2.0.  Can this be done? Exactly how would I obtain a firmware file and load it?  I do have access to the Bricxx Command Center, if required.

Comment: Not a definitive answer, but I really doubt the hardware is similar enough 10+ years later that you can just re-flash some firmware.

Comment: Actually, it's the exact same hardware.

Answer (score 8):

The hardware of RCX 2.0 is identical to 1.5, and the only difference between these two and version 1.0 is the charging port which had been removed. So they're compatible and you can indeed use a newer firmware on an older brick.

You'll need the Mindstorms 2.5 SDK, which contains the latest official firmware. It's probably not on the LEGO site any more, but [Philo](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/550/philo) has [saved it for posterity on his site](http://www.philohome.com/sdk25/sdk25.htm).

You may also want to use a compatible, but faster, firwmare from Dick Swan, you'll find it [archived here](http://www.elenafrancesco.org/old/lego/index.html).

As for uploading it to the RCX brick, I think there's indeed an option for it in BrickCC but I'm not too sure where, so I can't help much there. It's probably in the documentation somewhere.

Comment: I confirm that Bricxcc can upload firmware to the RCX (in tools menu)